# When I am trying to execute a shell script through perl it is providing me the result but all in one line. How to correct it?

Tags: perl, shell

When I am trying to execute a shell script through perl-CGI it is providing me the result but all in one line. But when I run the shell script it is showing the result in proper format. Please guide me how to make it proper.

Below is the perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard);

exec("sh /tmp/att.sh -t v2  --help");
print end_html
```

Please help me in resolving it.

Comment: What do you mean "all on one line"?  What is the contents of `att.sh`?

Comment: @MichaelT Just a reminder if you print plain text in an HTML context it look like one long line.

Comment: It looks like there's no value in using Perl at all here.  You could probably just invoke the shell script directly.

Comment: You can wgap you output by <pre> tag in the output: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Answer (score 6):

Add this before your `exec`:

```
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
```

You can safely remove the `print end_html;` since it is never executed anyway.

In fact, anything after your `exec` is never executed. If you want to execute more Perl after your shell call look at `system` or some other method (see [this link](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands)).

If you want to embed your output in HTML you have to get a little more sophisticated and use backticks or open a pipe since you will want to capture the output and HTML escape before print.

```
use CGI qw/escapeHTML/;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

printf "<pre>%s</pre>\n", escapeHTML(`sh /tmp/att.sh -t v2  --help`);
```

EDIT (per request by @ysth): what is `<pre>`

Per [W3C documentation on `pre`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-PRE)

> The PRE element tells visual user agents that the enclosed text is "preformatted". When handling preformatted text, visual user agents:
>
> - May leave white space intact.
> - May render text with a fixed-pitch font.
> - May disable automatic word wrap.
> - Must not disable bidirectional processing.

Comment: add explanation of how html treats newlines *not* in `<pre>`?